Cargar datos a ReportViewer desde Informe RDLC
Por favor ayuda con este problema que tengo.
haber comienzo explicando mi problema necesito cargar reportes, y para eso estoy usando los reportes nativos de VS 2022.
Les comento que tengo hecho hasta el momento.
1 Creé mi archivo .xsd llamado DataSetInformes.xsd
2 Agregué mi archivo RDLC
3 Agregué un Formulario llamado Informes dentro de la CapaPresentacion
3.1 Agregué otro formulario llamdo Ventas dentro de la carpeta Informes
4 Agregué mi informe RDLC, llamado TicketUltimaVenta
5 Agregué un ReportViewer llamdo ReportViewer1 al formulario
6 Agregué el conjunto de datos al RDLC
7 Desde las opciones del ReportViewer lo vinculé con el RDLC.
Muy bien, cuando elegí el RDLC se agregaron al pie del formulario
dataSetInformes
grupoBindingSource
grupoTableAdapter
y en el evento load del formulario se agregó este código
// TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'dataSetInformes.Grupo' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.

this.grupoTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSetInformes.Grupo);
Que sucede, aveces funciona y aveces no funciona, me dice que no tengo asigado un Dataset, o que el archivo .RDLC, no existe en la carpeta Debug, (habilité la opción copiar siempre) del RDLC,
Bueno pero yo quiero hacerlo mediante código para que deje de darme errores, para ello hice este código:
DataSetInformes dataSet = new DataSetInformes();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "TicketUltimaVenta.rdlc";
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSetInformes", dataSet.Tables["Grupo"]);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

El cual no funciona tampoco, por favor ayudenme a resolverlo, puesto que no se donde está la falla que esto cometiendo.
les mostraré fragmento de imagenes que tengo dentro del proyecto para que puedan ayudarme con mas facilidad
El directorio



les agradezco ayudarme a ver donde está mi error
Roberto

Tal vez ayude a alguien en alguna oportunidad, he probado con este código, y funcionó muy bien.
Código para visualizar un informe .RDLC con ReportViewer mediante código
    GrupoTableAdapter grupoTableAdapter = new GrupoTableAdapter();

DataSetInformes dataSet = new DataSetInformes();

try
{
    
    grupoTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Grupo);

    
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "TicketUltimaVenta.rdlc";

    
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataSet.Tables["Grupo"]);

    
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

    // refresh report
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error loading report: " + ex.Message);
}
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

Doy por cerrada mi pregunta y voy a seleccionar como la solución a mi problema
Gracias
